# Excel VBA Code to pull SSRS data as a dataset

Tags: excel, vba, reporting-services, dataset

I can’t seem to find a solution for my problem no matter how much I Google.

(Please excuse my verbosity in the following explanation)

My process is that I have to go to the SSRS web page, run my report (with parameters), and finally export as an excel file.  Once all that is done I can execute my couple thousand lines of VBA code to import the raw data I just downloaded and apply my business logic. Now I’m able to make My pretty charts and graphs. For lots of reasons I won’t enumerate here, I need to further automate this.

What I would like to do is change my code so it will just pull the data directly into my Excel spreadsheet without having to have first saved it as a file.

The Googling I have done so far suggests I would be pulling it into a dataset, then work with that dataset object to consume my data.

Does anyone have VBA code that demonstrates how to connect to the SSRS server, call my specific report (with parameters) and, and return the results as ( I’m guessing as a dataset),and read that into my spreadsheet?

Comment: Can you provide the website address? I might have a solution for you that uses IE Automation to extract the contents of a site. I have done this many times, however if it is a secure site, you may find issues with an automated process flagging as virus activity...had my bank disable my login because of this, now I just copy the data myself to avoid this issue.

Comment: Are you able to just query the database directly?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Our corporate policy won’t allow me to do that.  I can only get the data through SSRS.

Comment: I would create a Powershell script that goes out and executes/saves the report to it's designated location, something like https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/10/14/automate-ssrs-report-generation-using-powershell/  I would then call that Powershell script from my VBA code and continue the chart/graph formatting when the Powershell script has completed.

Answer (score -1):

Excel is providing facility to connect to the database and run query. You can execute the SP's query from excel

Once you got the data, you can apply your chart logic in excel.

Please refer the [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-SQL-Server-database-to-your-workbook-Power-Query-22c39d8d-5b60-4d7e-9d4b-ce6680d43bad). Hope it will help you.

Comment: The poster mentioned he is not able to connect directly to the database to execute a SP, he must go through SSRS